# How to satisfy totally_ordered for a custom type without spaceship comparison operator (ranges::is_sorted, ranges::sort)

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Consider the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>
#include <cassert>

// The type is defined in legacy code and we can not change it
struct A
{
   int a;
};

bool operator <(const A &a1, const A &a2)
{
   return a1.a < a2.a;
}

int main()
{
   assert(A {} < A{}); // OK
   std::vector<A> c;
   assert(std::ranges::is_sorted(c)); // compilation error
}
```

The code can be fixed by adding the "spaceship" comparison operator to A:

```
auto operator<=>(const A &) const = default;
```

However, defining it outside of a class works with the first `assert`, but not the second:

```
auto operator <=>(const A &a1, const A &a2) { return a1.a <=> a2.a; }
```

Is it possible to satisfy the requirements of `ranges::less` without modifying `A`?

Comment: `assert(A {} < A{}); // OK`? self less comparison should be `false`...

Comment: @Jarod42 It compiles and the assertion fires, whereas the second is a compilation error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [provide an `==`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62f096e8dc1a3aa2) as well as `<=>`. `std::ranges::less` requires `std::totally_ordered` not just `std::strict_weak_order`, so `==` is also needed. Unless `default`ed, `<=>` doesn't synthesize `==`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>
#include <cassert>

// The type is defined in legacy code and we can not change it
struct A
{
   int a;
};

auto operator <=>(const A &a1, const A &a2) { return a1.a <=> a2.a; }
auto operator ==(const A &a1, const A &a2) { return a1.a == a2.a; }

int main()
{
   assert(A {} < A{}); // Comparison exists
   std::vector<A> c;
   assert(std::ranges::is_sorted(c)); // Comparison exists
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Caleth. What is the explanation for this requirement?

Comment: If you used (non-`ranges`) `std::less` you wouldn't need `==`

Comment: I see. But the problem is that even if I have both `operator <` and `operator ==` defined for A, it still does not compile. Only the combination of both <=> and == works. And I supposed `operator <=>` "included" `operator ==`. I mean for `ranges::less` case, not the `std::less` case.

Comment: I see you have edited your answer and now it is clear. Thank you again for the explanation.

Comment: `ranges::less` needs all of `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` and `==`. I don't think it's a technical reason, but a prod to use `<=>`